# RxJs - get duplicate items of two observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I need to get duplicate items of two streams. I think I almost managed to do it, but only if those items that are duplicate of second stream, goes in order. For ex:

This works:

```
first = Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
second = Observable.of(2, 3, 1)
```

But this doesn't:

```
first = Observable.of(1, 4, 3)
second = Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
```

When my loop gets to the 4, it breaks:

> EmptyError {name: "EmptyError", stack: "EmptyError: no elements in
>   sequence↵    at new Emp…e
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:161:22)", message: "no
>   elements in sequence"}

Whole my code is in one function, you can copy/paste and test it:

```
findDublicates() {

  let match = 0; // setting it to 0, so later could assign other number
  let keys = []; // list of maching keys 
  let elementAt = 0; // index of item of first observable          

  let allKeys$;
  let validKeys$;

  // counting the length of both observables, so this will be the number of loops
  // that checks for dublicates
  let allKeysLength;
  let validKeysLength;
  let allKeysLength$ = Observable.of(2, 1, 4, 5, 7).count()
    allKeysLength$.subscribe(val => allKeysLength = val)
  let validKeysLength$ = Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 8, 5).count()
    validKeysLength$.subscribe(val => validKeysLength = val)   

  let cycles = Math.min(allKeysLength,validKeysLength); // length of the shorter observable               

  // wrapping it in a function so when called variables will take new values
  function defineObs() {

    allKeys$ = Observable.of(2, 1, 4, 5, 7)
      .elementAt(elementAt).take(1);

    validKeys$ = Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 8, 5)
      .filter((x) => (x === match)).first(); 
   }

  for (var i=0; i<=cycles; i++) {

    defineObs();

    allKeys$.subscribe(
      function (val) { match = val },
      function (err) { console.log(err) },
      function () { console.log('Done filter')}
    );
    validKeys$.subscribe(
      function (val) { keys.push(val) },
      function (err) { console.log(err) },
      function () { console.log('Done push')}
    );

    elementAt += 1;
    cycles -= 1;

  } 

  return console.log(keys);

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why aren’t you handling this all using observables. You’re trying to apply a different paradigm that doesn’t work so well with observables.

Comment: I also think that this might be done only with observables, but I am new to RP, so have no idea how to do it

Comment: So feel free to show how to get duplicates of two streams :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about which stream emits the first value of a set of duplicates, you may just merge them and treat as finding duplicate values on a single stream:

```
first.merge(second)
     .scan(([ dupes, uniques ], next) =>
       [ uniques.has(next) ? dupes.add(next) : dupes, uniques.add(next) ], 
       [ new Set(), new Set() ]
     )
     .map(([ dupes ]) => dupes)
```

Note: the Sets above are immutable, to avoid undefined behavior in `scan`.

Comment: This is brilliant! You know RP and functional programming really well as I see. Nice job. I will accept when I fully understand what the heck is this :D

Comment: @J.D. I can lay down the gist: after merging all items from both streams into one, we grow a Set out of all items (`uniques`), and add to `dupes` only if the `next` item was seen before. `scan` is perhaps the densest part of the snippet, so I suggest [the docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html). `scan` will give us all intermediate values of both Sets, so `map` extracts just the `dupes`.

Comment: @J.D. Operators and chaining are designed to make behaviors obvious and painless. Usually, there is a _single_ shortest and most robust approach, where it pays to commit the operators to memory. Otherwise, pinning down exactly what is needed is usually the biggest effort. Happy Rx learning!

Comment: Thanks. In fact my first try was very similar - merge and then scan, but failed miserably. Even now I am not fully aware how `scan` passes that `next`.. Also `Set()` was something new... So yes, I will dig docs a bit more

Answer (score 0):

I would check up on `Observable.combineLatest` and the `scan` method on an observable sequence.

Here’s what I’m thinking, combine the two observables using `combineLatest` and apply the `scan` operator on that. You can even use a `Set` to ensure uniqueness or even a `map` and `filter`.